# What is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i)$?

Tags: field-theory

Is it $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i) = \{ a+b\sqrt[4]{3}i+c\sqrt[4]{9}i + d\sqrt[4]{27} : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \}$? Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\sqrt[3]{2}i$ is not killed by a polynomial of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The degree $3$ term, after valuation, is a rational multiple of $i$ whereas the degree $1$ term necessarily is an irrational multiple of $i$, so that the imaginary parts can not possibly add up to zero.

Comment: Note if $\alpha = \sqrt[3] 2\,i$ then $\alpha^2= -\sqrt[3] 4$ and $\alpha^3=-2i$, thus both $i$ and $\sqrt[3] 2$ are in your field, which therefore has degree at least $6$.  In particular, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$ is a proper subfield of your field.

Comment: @Suzet The original question asked me to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ and$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i)$ are isomorphic, but first I wanted to understand simpler examples.

Comment: Oddly, that example is significantly easier than the one you posed, as both values are roots of the irreducible polynomial $x^4-3$.

Comment: @lulu Then I should modify the question

Comment: As a suggestion:  don't edit a question to the extent that it makes all the comments irrelevant.  That level of modification makes it hard for future users to follow the post at all.  At least leave the original question in the post, so people can understand the responses.

Comment: As a general point:  if $\alpha, \,\beta$ are two roots of the same polynomial (irreducible over $\mathbb Q$) then $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\beta)$.

Comment: @lulu That solves the question completely, I forgot that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstractly, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i)$ is obtained by adjoining a root of $x^4-3$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

The same description applies to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$.

Hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$.

A concrete isomorphism sends $\sqrt[4]{3}i$ to $\sqrt[4]{3}$.

If $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree $n$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is the set of rational linear combinations of $\alpha^k$ for $k=0,\dots,n$.

Therefore,
$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}i)=
\{ a+b\sqrt[4]{3}i+c\sqrt[4]{9} + d\sqrt[4]{27}i : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \}
$.